# Purpose of extension of measures?

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

I have recently learned some abstract concept of induced measures such as outer measure, inner measure, outer measurable, and complete measures on sigma-ring. I am confused as to what is the purpose of introducing these extensions? (some intuitive answers?)

I also learned about the existence of a nonmeasurable set(Vitali set), and cantor set as Lebesgue measurable but not Borel set.

Comment: the Cantor set is Borelian: it is just the intersection of countable many compact sets. By the other side the completion of a measure space have theoretic importance, in practice generally it is enough with a non-complete measure space, and the generation of a measure from an outer measure is essential by example for probability theory